# Trigger to addSubview method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, addsubview

I'm looking for a way - how to detect: my `UIView` was added as subview to some other view to adapt it's frame to superview.

F.e I should put my `UIView` to the bottom of parent view (but I don't know which parent will be... :| )

The only way that I can see is override parent `addSubview` method, but I don't have access to it.

I would like to have delegate method like:

```
- (void)viewDidAddedAsSubview:(UIView)parentView
```

or smth like that

Maybe, somebody knows how to do this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the view you are adding is a custom `UIView` class, then override the `willMoveToSuperview:` or the `didMoveToSuperView` method. Take into account that these are called when the view is removed as well.

If the view you are adding is not custom `UIView` then you can add an observer on the view's `superview` property.